# Android emulator browser unfortunately has stopped

Tags: android, eclipse, macos, emulation, adt

OSX 10.9
IDE Eclipse ADT

Fresh installation... when start emulator and open navigator, got crash message.

```
12-04 09:04:18.680: E/BufferQueue(369): [ScreenshotClient] dequeueBuffer: SurfaceComposer::createGraphicBuffer failed
12-04 09:04:19.720: A/libc(968): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000000 (code=1), thread 970 (vold)
12-04 09:04:20.850: E/VoldConnector(369): got -1 reading with start = 0
12-04 09:04:20.860: E/VoldConnector(369): closing stream for vold
12-04 09:04:20.890: E/VoldConnector(369): Communications error: java.io.IOException: No such file or directory
12-04 09:04:20.920: E/VoldConnector(369): Error in NativeDaemonConnector: java.io.IOException: No such file or directory
12-04 09:04:28.610: E/WindowManager(369): Starting window AppWindowToken{b40b8180 token=Token{b40ce520 ActivityRecord{b40d8c90 u0 com.android.browser/.BrowserActivity t5}}} timed out
12-04 09:05:19.730: E/NativeDaemonConnector.ResponseQueue(369): Timeout waiting for response
12-04 09:05:19.730: E/VoldConnector(369): timed-out waiting for response to 9 volume mkdirs /storage/sdcard/Android/data/com.android.browser/files/
12-04 09:05:19.790: E/AndroidRuntime(1069): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-04 09:05:19.790: E/AndroidRuntime(1069): Process: com.android.browser, PID: 1069
12-04 09:05:19.790: E/AndroidRuntime(1069): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider com.android.browser.provider.SnapshotProvider: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-04 09:05:19.790: E/AndroidRuntime(1069):     at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:4774)
12-04 09:05:19.790: E/AndroidRuntime(1069):     at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4366)
12-04 09:05:19.790: E/AndroidRuntime(1069):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4306)
12-04 09:05:19.790: E/AndroidRuntime(1069):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1400(ActivityThread.java:135)
12-04 09:05:19.790: E/AndroidRuntime(1069):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1457)
12-04 09:05:19.790: E/AndroidRuntime(1069):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
12-04 09:05:19.790: E/AndroidRuntime(1069):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-04 09:05:19.790: E/AndroidRuntime(1069):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4998)
12-04 09:05:19.790: E/AndroidRuntime(1069):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-04 09:05:19.790: E/AndroidRuntime(1069):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
12-04 09:05:19.790: E/AndroidRuntime(1069):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
12-04 09:05:19.790: E/AndroidRuntime(1069):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
12-04 09:05:19.790: E/AndroidRuntime(1069):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-04 09:05:19.790: E/AndroidRuntime(1069): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-04 09:05:19.790: E/AndroidRuntime(1069):     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1467)
12-04 09:05:19.790: E/AndroidRuntime(1069):     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1415)
12-04 09:05:19.790: E/AndroidRuntime(1069):     at android.os.storage.IMountService$Stub$Proxy.mkdirs(IMountService.java:750)
12-04 09:05:19.790: E/AndroidRuntime(1069):     at android.app.ContextImpl.ensureDirsExistOrFilter(ContextImpl.java:2160)
12-04 09:05:19.790: E/AndroidRuntime(1069):     at android.app.ContextImpl.getExternalFilesDirs(ContextImpl.java:856)
12-04 09:05:19.790: E/AndroidRuntime(1069):     at android.app.ContextImpl.getExternalFilesDir(ContextImpl.java:839)
12-04 09:05:19.790: E/AndroidRuntime(1069):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.getExternalFilesDir(ContextWrapper.java:210)
12-04 09:05:19.790: E/AndroidRuntime(1069):     at com.android.browser.provider.SnapshotProvider.getOldDatabasePath(SnapshotProvider.java:116)
12-04 09:05:19.790: E/AndroidRuntime(1069):     at com.android.browser.provider.SnapshotProvider.migrateToDataFolder(SnapshotProvider.java:123)
12-04 09:05:19.790: E/AndroidRuntime(1069):     at com.android.browser.provider.SnapshotProvider.onCreate(SnapshotProvider.java:137)
12-04 09:05:19.790: E/AndroidRuntime(1069):     at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1589)
12-04 09:05:19.790: E/AndroidRuntime(1069):     at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1560)
12-04 09:05:19.790: E/AndroidRuntime(1069):     at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:4771)
12-04 09:05:19.790: E/AndroidRuntime(1069):     ... 12 more
12-04 09:12:42.500: E/SoundPool(369): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
12-04 09:12:42.530: E/SoundPool(369): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
12-04 09:12:42.530: E/SoundPool(369): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
12-04 09:12:42.550: E/SoundPool(369): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
12-04 09:12:42.550: E/SoundPool(369): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
12-04 09:12:42.560: E/SoundPool(369): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressStandard.ogg
12-04 09:12:42.590: E/SoundPool(369): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressSpacebar.ogg
12-04 09:12:42.630: E/gralloc_goldfish(49): gralloc_alloc: Mismatched usage flags: 246 x 410, usage 333
12-04 09:12:42.640: E/(49): GraphicBufferAlloc::createGraphicBuffer(w=246, h=410) failed (Invalid argument), handle=0x0
12-04 09:12:42.640: E/BufferQueue(369): [ScreenshotClient] dequeueBuffer: SurfaceComposer::createGraphicBuffer failed
12-04 09:12:42.660: E/SoundPool(369): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressDelete.ogg
12-04 09:12:42.680: E/SoundPool(369): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressReturn.ogg
12-04 09:12:42.680: E/SoundPool(369): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressInvalid.ogg
12-04 09:12:43.570: A/libc(1082): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000000 (code=1), thread 1084 (vold)
12-04 09:12:44.470: E/VoldConnector(369): got -1 reading with start = 0
12-04 09:12:44.490: E/VoldConnector(369): closing stream for vold
12-04 09:12:44.530: E/VoldConnector(369): Communications error: java.io.IOException: No such file or directory
12-04 09:12:44.560: E/VoldConnector(369): Error in NativeDaemonConnector: java.io.IOException: No such file or directory
12-04 09:12:52.640: E/WindowManager(369): Starting window AppWindowToken{b3fca808 token=Token{b4092f10 ActivityRecord{b4092db0 u0 com.android.browser/.BrowserActivity t6}}} timed out
12-04 09:13:43.590: E/NativeDaemonConnector.ResponseQueue(369): Timeout waiting for response
12-04 09:13:43.590: E/VoldConnector(369): timed-out waiting for response to 12 volume mkdirs /storage/sdcard/Android/data/com.android.browser/files/
12-04 09:13:43.620: E/AndroidRuntime(1091): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-04 09:13:43.620: E/AndroidRuntime(1091): Process: com.android.browser, PID: 1091
12-04 09:13:43.620: E/AndroidRuntime(1091): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider com.android.browser.provider.SnapshotProvider: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-04 09:13:43.620: E/AndroidRuntime(1091):     at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:4774)
12-04 09:13:43.620: E/AndroidRuntime(1091):     at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4366)
12-04 09:13:43.620: E/AndroidRuntime(1091):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4306)
12-04 09:13:43.620: E/AndroidRuntime(1091):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1400(ActivityThread.java:135)
12-04 09:13:43.620: E/AndroidRuntime(1091):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1457)
12-04 09:13:43.620: E/AndroidRuntime(1091):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
12-04 09:13:43.620: E/AndroidRuntime(1091):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-04 09:13:43.620: E/AndroidRuntime(1091):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4998)
12-04 09:13:43.620: E/AndroidRuntime(1091):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-04 09:13:43.620: E/AndroidRuntime(1091):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
12-04 09:13:43.620: E/AndroidRuntime(1091):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
12-04 09:13:43.620: E/AndroidRuntime(1091):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
12-04 09:13:43.620: E/AndroidRuntime(1091):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-04 09:13:43.620: E/AndroidRuntime(1091): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-04 09:13:43.620: E/AndroidRuntime(1091):     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1467)
12-04 09:13:43.620: E/AndroidRuntime(1091):     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1415)
12-04 09:13:43.620: E/AndroidRuntime(1091):     at android.os.storage.IMountService$Stub$Proxy.mkdirs(IMountService.java:750)
12-04 09:13:43.620: E/AndroidRuntime(1091):     at android.app.ContextImpl.ensureDirsExistOrFilter(ContextImpl.java:2160)
12-04 09:13:43.620: E/AndroidRuntime(1091):     at android.app.ContextImpl.getExternalFilesDirs(ContextImpl.java:856)
12-04 09:13:43.620: E/AndroidRuntime(1091):     at android.app.ContextImpl.getExternalFilesDir(ContextImpl.java:839)
12-04 09:13:43.620: E/AndroidRuntime(1091):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.getExternalFilesDir(ContextWrapper.java:210)
12-04 09:13:43.620: E/AndroidRuntime(1091):     at com.android.browser.provider.SnapshotProvider.getOldDatabasePath(SnapshotProvider.java:116)
12-04 09:13:43.620: E/AndroidRuntime(1091):     at com.android.browser.provider.SnapshotProvider.migrateToDataFolder(SnapshotProvider.java:123)
12-04 09:13:43.620: E/AndroidRuntime(1091):     at com.android.browser.provider.SnapshotProvider.onCreate(SnapshotProvider.java:137)
12-04 09:13:43.620: E/AndroidRuntime(1091):     at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1589)
12-04 09:13:43.620: E/AndroidRuntime(1091):     at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1560)
12-04 09:13:43.620: E/AndroidRuntime(1091):     at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:4771)
12-04 09:13:43.620: E/AndroidRuntime(1091):     ... 12 more
```

Comment: it looks like you're trying to open a file that doesn't exist, can you show us the code that caused this ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Seems like there is an issue with the sdcard allocated to the emulator, The error in hand is a IO exception and a Nullpointer exception probability because the sd is not readable hence the browser can't be instatiated.. just create another emulator or play around with the sd allocation option.